# Modifying scope object values in checkbox using ngchange

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Forgive if this is a newbie error but I think this must be really simple and I am obviously missing something..

I have the following ngrepeat:

```
       <div class="panel-body" data-ng-repeat="participant in activity.Participants" ng-show="showp" ng-init="participant.CheckInTime ='not set'"> <--The 'init' is for debug
            {{getparticipantName(participant.ParticipantID)}}

            Check in = {{participant.CheckInTime}}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="participant.CheckedIn"
                   ng-change="setToNowOrNull(participant.CheckedIn, 'participant.CheckInTime')">

            <br />
            Check in = {{participant.CheckInTime}}

        </div>
```

Which is nested within another ng-repeat which defines the controller etc. and that works fine. But when I click the checkbox, the settoNowOrNull function gets called, changes the value as it should, but this isn't returned to the participant.CheckInTime .. here is the function:

```
        $scope.setToNowOrNull = function (deciderbool, thingtoset) {
        if (deciderbool)  //its been set to true.
        {
            $scope[thingtoset] = Date.now();
        }
        else //its been cleared to false
        {
            $scope[thingtoset] == null;
        }
    }
```

I added the $scope[thingtoset] after reading another question on here but to no avail.. the same with the single quotes around 'participant.CheckInTime' in the ng-change line. (This is supposed to pass the object not the value?).. 
I'm obviously not getting something, and I'd have thought I could have done it in the html angular anyway rather than needing to call the controller for something so trivial - I just need to record the Date.Now() into the participant.CheckInTime. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Try using $watch to your model to detect change.

Comment: just pass one argument...the participant object, then you have the full object in controller function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="participant.CheckedIn"
       ng-change="setToNowOrNull(participant)">


$scope.setToNowOrNull = function (participant) {
    if (participant.CheckedIn)  //its been set to true.
    {
        participant.CheckInTime = Date.now();
    }
    else //its been cleared to false
    {
        participant.CheckInTime == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. that works.. but to be honest I don't really understand why it does, when passing in participant.CheckInTime doesn't. I guess it is to do with passing the object as opposed to an element of it and one being passed by reference, the other by value? but tbh I am new to JS and Angular so am a little bit confused by that. But thanks again. Brett

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your approach, particularly with

`$scope[thingtoset] = Date.now();`

Using value being passed into function this would be

```
$scope['participant.CheckInTime'] = Date.now();
```

This isn't the same as

```
$scope.participant.CheckInTime;
```

The whole string represents one object key and would have to be parsed into parts to get 2 levels out of it. Essentially it's invalid syntax for what you had hoped to accomplish

Even if it was valid there is no such object on your scope since `participant` is an alias for an object in the view. That object is within the array `activity.Participants`.

In conclusion, pass the actual object into your function and work with the whole object

If you want a generic method for multiple properties it would need to be more like:

```
$scope.setToNowOrNull = function (object, key){

   switch(key){
        case 'CheckInTime':
          // code for this key
         break;
   }
}
```

Then in markup would use:

```
<input ng-change="setToNowOrNull(participant, 'CheckInTime')">
```

I suspect that you likely don't need such a generic method and can simply pass a single argument, the participant object, for that specific change handler

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.. I might need to use a generic one in the future and so it is my normal habit to try to make things as generic as possible. Your explanation was really useful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Within the ng-repeat, the object has its own scope, therefore when you try to write into **$scope[thingtoset]**, instead of overriding the parent scope's corresponding object, you just create another object with the same name in the lower scope. Instead you can create an object in the upper scope, say **$scope.thingHolder**, and when this function is called, it can update **$scope.thingHolder[thingtoset]**. Then you will be able to observe the changes correctly in the upper scope too.